# Is there a way to get the filename (or title) of a completed print job?

Tags: printing, cups

The `lpq -a` lists, among other things, the name of each file printed.

```
Rank    Owner    Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  myuser   2       version.txt                     1024 bytes
1st     myuser   8       691227_1399095378.raw           3072 bytes
```

It appears that the jobs listed correspond to those shown by `lpstat -Wnot-completed`.  But is there a way to get `lpq` (or any other CUPS program) to show the filenames of jobs that are completed?

Comment: lp man page: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?lp
-m -- Sends an email when the job is completed.
Not sure, if it sends a filename.

Answer (score 2):

```
less /var/log/cups/page_log
```

shows me:

```
hp-oj-5510 243 stefan [24/Apr/2012:10:36:05 +0200] 1 1STATE: - localhost xy-file-46 - -
hp4p 244 stefan [24/Apr/2012:10:38:33 +0200] 1 1 - localhost Unbenannt1 - -
hp-oj-5510 243 stefan [24/Apr/2012:10:39:09 +0200] 2 1INFO: - localhost xy-file-46 - -
hp-oj-5510 246 stefan [24/Apr/2012:10:40:28 +0200] 1 1STATE: - localhost xy-file-46 - -
hp-oj-5510 246 stefan [24/Apr/2012:10:43:37 +0200] 2 1INFO: - localhost xy-file-46 - -
hp-oj-5510 247 stefan [24/Apr/2012:10:43:50 +0200] 1 1STATE: - localhost Unbenannt1 - -
```

The file on hp4p wasn't printed, and I don't know details of the file-format.

[But the cups webinterface](http://localhost:631/jobs?which_jobs=completed) has a section `jobs` and therein `completed jobs`, (translated from german - the words may differ).

The link goes to localhost - maybe your server is running on a different machine. Unfortunately the filename is only given without path, but with locate, it might in many cases be possible, to reconstruct which file was printed.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, if you open the file by firefox, and print it, you can see that the full path filename will be listed in the /var/log/cups/page_log. If you print the file by other app, or by cmd line, then only the file name itself is logged.