# Logging full paths to printed files in CUPS

Tags: logs, cups

We are trying to configure the CUPS printing service into the protected enterprise network, and we need to store full paths of printed files (instead of local filenames without directory, as it is implemented by default in `/var/log/cups/…`) in logs.

In [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37482/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-filename-or-title-of-a-completed-print-job) it is said that there are some solutions to define exactly which files has been printed, but what are they?

Has anybody managed to customize CUPS in this way? The OS is RHEL 6.4.